# Git Commit Characters

Tags: git

I had a problem using this git command:

```
git commit -m 'redirect from "/admin" to "/admin/"; wasn't able to use "[/]?$"'
```

It keeps going to the next line when I hit enter. What's wrong with that command and will this help?:

```
git commit --cleanup=verbatim -m 'redirect from "/admin" to "/admin/"; wasn't able to use "[/]\?$"'
```

Comment: you have `'` in the word `wasn't`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wasn't` has a `'` in it, so you have an unterminated string constant in your commandline. Because of shell quoting rules, the best you can easily do is `wasn'\''t`. I would suggest writing your commit messages in an editor, though :)

Comment: I use PyCharm, would you recommend that I use that? And great catch by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
git commit -m "redirect from \"admin\" to \"admin\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the double quote marks as the outer marks:

> git commit --cleanup=verbatim -m "redirect from '/admin' to '/admin/'; wasn't able to use '[/]\?$'"

The inner single quote mark in `wasn't` shouldn't be a problem this way.